# Jobs getting stuck in the queue

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, jobs

I have a `laravel 5.8` application in which I have a `Job` that runs in queue and I am using `RabbitMQ` with laravel package [Laravel Queue RabbitMQ](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/tree/v7.5.0) version `5.7.0`. So if I have 370 records in my file it processes fine but if records are greater than that, then it, for some reason, retries and retries and keeps in that cycle. Here is my `Rabbit MQ` config:

```
'worker' => [
    'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
    'worker' => env('RABBITMQ_WORKER', 'default'),
    'factory_class' => Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory::class,
    'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
    'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
    'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST'),
    'login' => env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN'),
    'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
    'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE'),
    'options' => [
        'exchange' => [
            'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME'),
            'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DECLARE', true),
            'type' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_TYPE', \Interop\Amqp\AmqpTopic::TYPE_DIRECT),
            'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_PASSIVE', false),
            'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DURABLE', true),
            'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_AUTODELETE', false),
            'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_ARGUMENTS'),
        ],
        'queue' => [
            'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', env('RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE')),
            'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE', true),
            'bind' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE_BIND', true),
            'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_PASSIVE', false),
            'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DURABLE', true),
            'exclusive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_EXCLUSIVE', false),
            'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_AUTODELETE', false),
            'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_ARGUMENTS'),
        ],
    ],
],
```

Here is the piece of code that I think is creating the issue:

```
foreach ($this->fileToArray() as $row) {
            $row = array_change_key_case($row, CASE_LOWER);
            // excel wrapper always returns an empty row, that's
            // why we only start counting if we get this far
            $this->recordCount++;

            try {
                $orderLine = $this->orderLineService->createOrderLineFromFileRecord($row);
                $this->recordsProcessedCount++;

                \Log::debug('$this->recordCount', [$this->recordCount]);

            } catch (InvalidOrderLineException $e) {
                $this->recordsSkippedCount++;

                $this->addMessageFromException($e);
            }
        }
```

And here is the createOrderLineFromFileRecord method:

```
public function createOrderLineFromFileRecord(Array $orderLineFileRecord)
    {
        $orderLine = $this->createStandAloneOrderLine($orderLineFileRecord);

        $orderLine->extraFields()->saveMany(
            $this->createExtraFieldsCollection($orderLineFileRecord)
        );

        return $orderLine;
    }
```

If I remove this part:

```
$orderLine->extraFields()->saveMany(
                $this->createExtraFieldsCollection($orderLineFileRecord)
            );
```

then it works fine. Also if I have 500 records in file and I process all of it then it returns with the same issue, stuck in queue, retries after retries but If I process 370 of those records it works fine and the rest 130 records separately then also works fine.

Also there is no erros shown in the logs.

I have Laravel 5.8 with mysql 5.7. memtory limit in ini is set to 512M. What could be the reason?

Comment: Better convert you jobs to smaller chunks